Active Directory Federation server - verification code by email
Does anyone know where or how I can set SMTP server details in the Active Directory Federation Service? I need this so ADFS can send a verification code to someone's email address.
My setup includes Windows Server 2022 with ADFS and Microsoft Exchange on-premises. I can't see a place to input details about my Exchange server in ADFS. Where is this located?
I tried reading the manual from Microsoft and researching many websites and forums. I can't find any information about this. It looks like nobody can send verification by email on an on-premise solution.

Microsoft does not provide a built-in SMTP server. You have to provide your own.
ADFS does not provide OTP functionality.
You can use a 3rd party solution or roll your own - both described here.

I can't see the answer to my question. It looks like nobody can send the code to the on-premise email.
You know, for fun, Microsoft has purposely hidden this setting. The reason? They want everyone to go to Azure and pay money. But I already found a solution, and now my on-premise setup can send emails with the code. Microsoft, screw off!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
